# Python Curses IRC/IM style updates

Tags: python, curses

How do I create a IRC/IM style update in a curses window.

Where all lines are moved up by one and the bottom line is replaced with the provided text?

So far I have managed to get a one line input box at the bottom and then one window above it with the height of the screen -1 but am unsure on inserting text.

I am inserting text with window.addstr() and deleting the line above it, but this doesn't seem to work!

Many thanks for any advice/hints,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have solved this myself after just trying loads of functions in window

```
wDebug.move(0,0)
wDebug.deleteln()
wDebug.addstr(4, 0, msg)
wDebug.refresh()
```

Is this the correct/best way?